# Vaneless ion wind generator: isn’t the maximum output theoretically limited?

Tags: efficiency, electrostatic, windturbine

I was thinking more specifically about the Dutch model of the kind EWICON : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaneless_ion_wind_generator

Here is what puzzles me:

1. If the wind is strong enough to carry all the charged droplets generated upstream, then above that threshold, the speed of the wind does not play any role. So it doesn’t seem to make an efficient use of the wind's energy.
2. If the current is not very high, then the efficiency is inherently low (like an air ionizer from the eighties).

Conversely, if said intensity is above a given threshold the stream of charged droplets is literally a charged cloud which will discharge onto any conductor in the vicinity, creating a local thunderstorm and causing chaos.

All in all, it sounds rather chimerical from the look of the blueprints alone.

Comment: Will the Betz limit still apply?

Comment: The ion-wind "turbine" must interact (is MUST present a mechanical load against air motion, else output watts is zero.) But if it halts the air entirely, then the output watts is also zero.   As with blade-turbine pitch and RPM, the e-field and the droplet-charge density must be adjusted to maximize the electrical output wattage.

Comment: My understanding of the basics of that device is: if you have a cloud of charges particles (electrons, protons, droplets) and you apply a tension to it between two electrodes, then said particles loose potential energy and gain kinetic energy that is how a linear accelerator of the type Van de Graaf or an electrospray nozzle in the source of a mass spectrometer works. The idea behind this device is to do exactly the opposite : One uses the energy of the wind to accelerate the charged droplets in the opposite direction (« upstream » ) so as to generate a current and a tension on the electrodes.

Comment: I wonder if it had enough power to light an LED ;)

Comment: That is the question! :-)

Comment: Thunderstorms generate electricity in the same fashion. They are quite powerful.

Comment: Yes, but thunderstorms are not a continuous stream it's more like the sudden discharge of a camera flash.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard of this concept before, but it seems to me that an essential element to address the problems you describe would be to continuously adjust the rate of charged droplet production (or the charge per droplet) to whatever quantity results in the wind blowing away the most charge. This is the principle of [maximum power point tracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_point_tracking) (MPPT) applied to this generation technology.

It *might* even be possible to get feedback or implicit control directly from the droplet emitting mechanism: when the density of charged droplets near the emitter is higher (because the wind is taking them away slower or not at all), the electric potential the “charging system” will experience, between its base and the electrode that the droplets exit from, will be higher.

Comment: This, in turn, would create a lot of problems. One would need a source of charged droplets not unlike a large array of electrosprays of the kind used e.g. in the sources of ESI mass spectrometers and they would have to be monitored (and maintained and replaced, for problems like clogging and so on).

Comment: @SergeHulne You asked about the problem of the wind speed / particle quantity / charge buildup. A practical mechanism for the droplet generator is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

The wind must be strong enough to dilute the ions enough to prevent the air from becoming conductive.

so with stronger wind a larger current can be used and more energy harvested.

Comment: Well, the wind acts as conveyor belt, carrying the charges (the charged droplets) against the electric force generated by the potential (upstream), hence producing an amount of work. With no wind they would just drift naturally downstream consuming energy . It’s not a problem of dilution/concentration as such. It’s just that if the intensity of the current as a whole isn’t rather negligeable, the stream of charged droplets is like a giant charged cloud in a storm or like a live wire transmitting a large current in mid air, ready to strike at random anything which looks like a lightning rod.